# Определение Panel в виде отдельного класса

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал `Panel` с кучей элементов, но нужна мне эта панель, для того что бы множить и отображать по необходимости в `FlowLayoutPanel`. Вот как сделать эту панель отдельным классом ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант создать пользовательский элемент управления и поместить в него `Panel` со всем необходимым.